# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modeltranslation'

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

I've created a django project, where I want to use modeltranslation, but I cant get it to work as I keep getting this error:

```
(portfolio_env) jonas@kea-dev: ~/portfolio_project 
(main|✚11…)% django makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jonas/portfolio_project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/jonas/portfolio_project/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modeltranslation'
```

It is installed in the venv:

```
(portfolio_env) jonas@kea-dev: ~/portfolio_project 
(main|✚11…)% pip list
Package                 Version
----------------------- ---------
asgiref                 3.7.2
Django                  5.0.2
django-cuser            2017.3.16
django-modeltranslation 0.18.11
django-tinymce          3.7.1
importlib-metadata      7.0.1
modeltranslation        0.25
phonenumbers            8.13.30
phonenumberslite        8.13.30
pip                     24.0
psycopg-binary          3.1.18
psycopg2-binary         2.9.9
python-dotenv           1.0.1
setuptools              65.5.0
sqlparse                0.4.4
style                   1.1.0
typing_extensions       4.9.0
zipp                    3.17.0
```

And I have added in the "INSTALLED_APPS" in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'portfolio_app',
]
```

I import the module in my translation.py like this:

```
from modeltranslation.translator import register, TranslationOptions
```

Anybody who knows whats wrong?

- I have tried to remove the venv and make a new one
- I have tried to downgrade to a older version of django